# How can I use a macro to group and average the values in an Excel column?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-excel-2011

I'm new here and I've been struggling with macro writing. I was wondering if anyone could help me out with making/explaining a macro that could be used in my data set.

I have an Excel file that looks something like this:

[image]

I basically want a macro that will go through the “fruit” column, recognize that as a separate fruit then average the freshness of that fruit based on their “group,” and then state that average and group next to the first cell of each group.

I feel like this is an easy macro but I can’t figure it out. How can this be done?

Thanks! It is appreciated!

Comment: Doesn't even need a macro, a formula is enough. Multiply freshness by If fruit = apple then 1 else 0, sum it, and divide by count of apple in the fruit column.

Comment: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/windows-and-office/two-ways-to-find-a-conditional-average-in-excel/ or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12592926/conditionally-average-excel-data-columns

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply!

But I don't think this will work for my excel sheet. I have over 100+ "Fruit" (not really fruit, just an example) and I want the average for each fruit in each group and I have 50 groups.

Its ~750,000 row excel file, so I'm trying not to do it manually...

Comment: Man, sounds like you need a pivot table...

Comment: @LearningTheMacros,,  manual Group in Column C is baseless or I can it's imaginary neither based on Fruits or their freshness level so that this will create problem to arrange them in an order to group !!

Answer (score 0):

This Macro will do the trick

```
Public Sub itemaverages()
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Set wks = ActiveSheet
    firstrow = 2
    resultcolumn = 6
    titletext = "AVG"
    resultrow = firstrow
    searching = True
    lastitemname = wks.Cells(firstrow, 1)
    lastitemfresh = wks.Cells(firstrow, 2)
    lastitemgroup = wks.Cells(firstrow, 3)
    itemtotal = lastitemfresh
    therow = firstrow + 1
    While searching
        countitem = 1
        sameitem = True
        While sameitem
            itemname = wks.Cells(therow, 1)
            itemfresh = wks.Cells(therow, 2)
            itemgroup = wks.Cells(therow, 3)
            If itemname <> "" Then
                If (itemname = lastitemname) And (itemgroup = lastitemgroup) Then
                    itemtotal = itemtotal + itemfresh
                    countitem = countitem + 1
                    therow = therow + 1
                    lastitemname = itemname
                    lastitemfresh = itemfresh
                    lastitemgroup = itemgroup
                Else
                    averagename = UCase(lastitemname) & " " & titletext
                    averagefresh = itemtotal / countitem
                    wks.Cells(resultrow, resultcolumn).Value = averagename & " " & averagefresh
                    wks.Cells(resultrow, resultcolumn + 1).Value = lastitemgroup
                    sameitem = False
                    lastitemname = itemname
                    lastitemfresh = itemfresh
                    lastitemgroup = itemgroup
                    itemtotal = itemfresh
                    resultrow = therow
                    therow = therow + 1
                End If
            Else
                sameitem = False
                searching = False
            End If
        Wend
    Wend
    a = MsgBox("Finished", vbInformation)
End Sub
```

Open VBA/Macros with Alt+F11, insert a new module under *ThisWorkbook*, and paste this code on the right side.

The variables `firstrow` and `resultcolumn` can be tweaked to suit to your needs.